# chain a sequence of processes in python

Tags: python, pandas, method-chaining

I would like to chain a sequence of processes in python. One of theses processes is create some variables and use the groupby function.

Actually, I want create a new dataframe from my original data base. I can do it in some lines, but I would like some more concise using chain. My original data base is 'df'. First, I create a new binary variable indicating if the feature 'var1' has certain propertie: NaN ou non NaN.

```py
data = df
data['aux1'] = data['var1'].map(math.isnan)
data['count'] = 1 
pie = data.groupby(['aux1'])['count'].sum()
```

In R, I can do something like this:

```
pie = df %>% select('var1') %>% mutate( aux1 = is.na('var1') , count = 1 ) 
          %>% group_by(aux1) %>% summarise(count = sum('count'))
```

Is there some chain in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare column `var1` with [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and for count use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
pie = data['var1'].isna().value_counts()
```

Or create column `aux1` by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and aggregate [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), helper column with `1` is not necessary:

```
pie = data.assign(aux1=data['var1'].isna()).groupby('aux1').size()
```

But column `count` is possible create:

```
pie = data.assign(aux1=data['var1'].isna(), count=1).groupby('aux1')['count'].sum()
```

Comment: But first, I need to create aux1. This variable is indicative: if 'var1' is NaN or non Nan. Can I create 'aux1' in the same line of code?